# How to detect iPad user tap on keyboard hide button?

Tags: ipad, ios, keyboard

In my app I have some complex logic surrounding the hiding and showing of the keyboard. I am interested in detecting when the user (who has an iPad) specifically taps on the iPad keyboard hide button:

[image]

I am *not* interested in detecting when the keyboard is supposed to hide, only when the user actually physically taps on this button. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

I was looking for an exact same solution, and I did found it in the documentation after all. You get a whole package of keyboard notifications:

```
- UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
- UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
- UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
- UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
- UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
- UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification
```

I was interested in "UIKeyboardWillHideNotification". So just implemented:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(KeyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Et voilà! Hope this helps, even it's an year late answer.

Comment: This notification is also send when view is rotating.
I am interested in this key only and was wandering if you have found another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Apple allows that, I'm afraid.

But maybe you could create an invisible view (`view.opaque = FALSE; view.alpha = 0;`) that's placed just above the aforementioned button which receives touches as the first responder (so that you get the event) and then forwards it to the next (the keyboard). However, I don't know if it's possible to place a view above the keyboard, even "illegally".